# Easy Dialog box in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am developing a minor ruby script for windows and need some suggestions.

This script will interact on the user's input and the only UI I would need is a small dialog box with 3 options -> Option 1 , Option 2 or Cancel. Depending on what the user clicks I will run my further methods. Is there any easy way to achieve this.

Have looked into a lot of ruby gems like fxruby, shoes which could help me to achieve this but is there any easier way like create a easy vb script and I get back a response code on what the user clicked? I don't want to use any gem for just a small pop dialog box.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Ruby itself does not contain any GUI; your goal is to be achieved with some specific GUI library binding. BTW, I would suggest you to use `shoes`. On the other hand, you may try to call some windows-specific dialog popup and try to handle it’s output within ruby.

Comment: You can try the Tk binding of ruby, which is part of ruby installation (on windows if selected during installation; you may have to install Tk): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm.